# How to query memory consumption by different processes over time in linux ubuntu virtual machine using Azure monitor\Log analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to query to memory consumption by different processes over time in Linux ubuntu virtual machine using Azure monitor\Log analytics workspace.

Comment: You can query 
```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "System"
| summarize by ObjectName,CounterName,CounterValue
```
to know the number of processes and Memory as ObjectName for Used Memory but getting it out of the box we can make use of [linux performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters#linux-performance-counters)

Comment: Try checking https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-count-how-many-processes-are-running-in-linux/ to directly get the metrics from vm

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT Could you please share a sample query